# Horizontal scroll view on ChipView

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I'm using [this ChipView library](https://github.com/Plumillon/ChipView) for textview chips that, when a ListView item is clicked, will add chip to the ChipView:

[image: "Search by Name or Email Address"]

I need a horizontal scroll view for the ChipView but it just "shrinks" and can't be displayed as usual when I wrap it with a HorizontalScrollView tag:

[image: Stacked names]

It works fine in a (vertical) scroll view:

[image: Names in rows]

How can I display the ChipView with a horizontal scrolling please?

My XML (ll_searchBar2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_searchBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_search" />

        <!-- Dummy item to prevent EditText from receiving focus -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed_searchField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Search by Name or Email Address"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_searchBar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.gamification.gamificationpagestudy.chipview.ChipView
                android:id="@+id/text_my_chip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffe0d9" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llBottomAction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#c6b0ff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ratingbar_full_material" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInvite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="INVITE (0)"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/invitationListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/llBottomAction"
    android:layout_below="@id/ll_searchBar"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
```

My activity:

```
public class FourteenthActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_twelveth);

    ChipView chipView = (ChipView) findViewById(R.id.text_my_chip);
    chipView.add(new Tag("chip1"));
    chipView.add(new Tag("chip2"));
    chipView.add(new Tag("chip3"));
    chipView.add(new Tag("chip4"));
    chipView.add(new Tag("chip5"));
    chipView.add(new Tag("chip6"));
    chipView.add(new Tag("chip7"));
    chipView.add(new Tag("chip8"));
    chipView.add(new Tag("chip9"));
    chipView.add(new Tag("chip10"));

}
public class Tag implements Chip {
    private String mName;
    private int mType = 0;

    public Tag(String name, int type) {
        this(name);
        mType = type;
    }

    public Tag(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return mName;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return mType;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: did you make this work by any chance ??

Answer (score 0):

Take LinearLayout as root layout. And then add ChipViews programatically.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100 ,100);
ChipView chipView = new ChipView(context);
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0);
chipView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
linearLayuot.addView(chipView);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Even set width and height manually in program, the chip would just went to next line when it met the end of width, the horizontal scrollview still doesn't work.

Comment: set LinearLayout orientation to "horizontal".

Comment: check this Git repository: https://github.com/activesince93/CustomViews

you will get some idea. Just set LinearLayout orientation "horizontal".